# Change html and Onclick for an <a>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm looking at old code not written by me, so changing the code drastically is not really an option.
I want to change the html for a document to vietnamese.

```
 <li id="menu-item-151" class="liLink"><a onclick="$('#register').click();">Enroll Now</a></li>
```

in another file I have

```
var  language = getCookie('language');
if (language == 'Vietnamese'){
  $("#menu-item-151").html("Dăng kí ngay") }
```

This works but causes the onclick functionality to disappear. How can I change change the text but keep on the onclick.

I have tried the following but that causes the onclick to always activate when the website appears.

```
document.getElementById("menu-item-151").setAttribute('onclick', $('#register').click())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because you're overwriting the HTML for the entire `li` element - which removes the `a` within it.

To fix the problem, change the content of the child `a` only, and I'd suggest using `text()` instead of `html()` in this case:

```
if (language == 'Vietnamese'){
  $("#menu-item-151 a").text("Dăng kí ngay") 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, I didnt realize you could put the child in